# How to calculate the following integral of the multiplication of two Bessel functions?

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

This integration has an analytical solution and its behavior is described by 1/r^2 function, but Mathematica gives some weird oscillating answer. Can anybody explain this and help me overcome this issue.

```
R  = 1500;
f[r_] := NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, r*k]*BesselJ[1, R*k], {k, 0, Infinity},AccuracyGoal -> 12]
sol = Table[Abs[f[r]]^2, {r, R, 2000, 10}];
ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Integrate[BesselJ[2, p*k]*BesselJ[1, R*k], {k, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> p > R]

Comment: Numerically `R = 1500;
f[r_] := NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, r*k]*BesselJ[1, R*k], {k, 0, Infinity}]
sol = Table[Abs[f[r]]^2, {r, R, 2000, 10}];
ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
R = 1500;
f[r_] := NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, r*k]*BesselJ[1, R*k], {k, 0, Infinity}]
sol = Table[Abs[f[r]]^2, {r, R, 2000, 10}];
ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi. So the problem was the AccuracyGoal? Why? Also, I get a warning NIntegrate::ncvb while calculating this.

Comment: @artalexan I'mon version 9, and NIntegrate doesn't show any warning. Perhaps a version or configuration mismatch